# How to open a port via password in linux server?

Tags: linux, port

I have a Linux server and I want to connect to it with a remote computer, how can I put a password for more security please?

I use netcat to connect to my server !
thanks a lot ...

Comment: Sad to say, you're unaware of how TCP/IP works. What you are asking for is impossible without writing your own custom stack.

Answer (score 1):

Updated.

- [SSH tunnel](http://www.engadget.com/2006/03/21/how-to-ssh-tunnels-for-secure-network-access/). 
  can add authentication and confidentiality to a communications protocol that lacks either.
- [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) - A sufficiently clever person can use socat to "wrap" some existing service and add prompting for a password.
- [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) - To move files securely I'd use secure-copy

Comment: thanks but I want just to open a port and connect to it via password.

Comment: Your use case may be too vague to answer. Maybe you can update the Q and elaborate a bit - what's listening at the server end?

Comment: Actually I'm an owner of a linux server and, we have some files that must be copy on it from the different locations,I opened a port on it and it works very well , but it's not secure, because via a simple port scanner the hackers can be access on it :(

Comment: What service is listening on that port?

Comment: @MikeRedford as RedGrittyBrick alludes to, you can't just "open a port" - something has to be listening there.  That "something" (FTP server? SSH server? rsync server? Web server?) should be what asks the user for a password, checks it against an authorized access list, etc...